Политики выполнения PowerShell (about_Execution_Policies)
Ничего не мешает мне поменять поменять политику на "Bypass" и спокойно запускать любые сценарии, но в то же время политика вроде оберегает мой ПК от нежелательных сценариев. Созрел вопрос можно ли лицензировать свой безобидный сценарий (просто выключает ПК по таймеру), чтобы я мог поставить политику "AllSigned". Она даст мне и сценарий запустить и от нежелательных огородит.

Можно, например, как описано тут или тут

В комментарии выше уже скинули хорошие статьи они подходят под ответ, единственное что добавил бы. Что как вы написали, если вы не разбираетесь в этой теме, вам тем более не нужно делать подпись для скрипка самому. Проще поставить политику "RemoteSigned":

А если вы хотите быть защищенным, тут главное голова на плечах и понимать, что можно скачивать и запускать.
